# как изменить имя пользователя ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Когда устанавливал проглядел, теперь в терминале отображается

```
victor@victor-HP-pavilion-g6-PC:~
```

как его сделать короче? например

```
victor@victor
```

Comment: Вы можете менять PS1 в ~/.bashrc как того душа пожелает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

судя по приведённому вами примеру, вы хотите изменить не имя пользователя, а имя компьютера.

в приведённой вами строке `victor@victor-HP-pavilion-g6-PC` (кстати, весьма распространённое и даже стандартизированное указание на пользователя компьютера — `пользователь@компьютер`. никогда не задумывались, что означает, например, `vasja-pupkin@mail.ru`?) имя пользователя — `victor`, а `victor-HP-pavilion-g6-PC` — это как раз имя компьютера.

изменять имя компьютера надо в двух файлах:

- `/etc/hostname`
- `/etc/hosts`

во втором из них это имя встретится в начале файла в строке примерно такого вида

```
127.0.1.1   имя
```

компьютер после этого надо будет перезагрузить.

---

имя текущего пользователя можно узнать, например, такими способами:

```
$ echo $USER
$ whoami
$ id
```

и т.п.

---

кстати, то, на что вы обратили внимание, называется [*command prompt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) и в оболочках *unix-подобных* операционных систем определяется содежимым переменной окружения [`PS1`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ps1)